# Return category info in fixed order

Tags: plugin, categories

Looking for suggestions for an active plugin or any obvious way to return basic categories info (category name, url_title, and image) with a fixed sort order based on category ids (i.e: sort="3|5|2"). I know I can query for this, but maybe someone has another suggestion.

Comment: Can it be the custom order used on CP?

Comment: Good idea, but the categories are being selected and sorted through a Low Variables variable, which outputs the selected  piped category ids in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the majority of my needs for category info in a fixed sort order, I found the plugin Categoree works: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/categoree .

Example:

```
{exp:categoree:pair show="{lv_snippet_piped_cat_list}" fixed="yes"}{category_name}, {/exp:categoree:pair}
```